# How many folders is ok to have in a folder?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

On my website, users have files so I create a folder for each user when they register.

for example

/userdata/USERID

If site grows and I have thousands of users I might end up having too many user folders in one folder so i decided to split them up.

for example

/userdata/1/USERID (first thousand users)

/userdata/2/USERID (second thousand users)

My questions is how much folders should I put in one subfolder? Is 1000 in each a good idea? more? less? Just want to make sure things run smoothly.

Comment: The answer to that depends entirely on the operating system & filesystem that your web host is using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always work to the rule of going for a maximum of ~1000 with ext2/ext3. I suspect that the choice of filesystem might affect your choice.

The absolute limit in ext3 is ~32k. Have a look for all of the gory details on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3

In terms of a hashing algorithm for your directories I'd recommend using the last digit of the id. If you calculate `$id % 10` and use that value it'll work a treat. That way you get an even distribution out of the box.

Comment: @James C, Can you please explain what hashing would be used for in this case? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: "hashing" as in which user to store in which directory. I'm recommending that it'd look like `5/1234`, `5/2345`, `1/102`, etc

Answer (score 1):

It depends mostly on the file system you are using.

You'll probably find it easier to use a pattern rather then splitting on arbitrary numbers. CPAN, for instance, uses

```
U/US/USERNAME
```

i.e. first letter / first two letters / full username

Comment: Thanks for advice. On my site usernames can be changed, I would prefer not to have to move folders around so CPAN's approach may not be suitable for me.

Comment: @user, I'd highly recommend using the CPAN approach, or `first_letter/second_letter/[etc]/full` and just accept that you'll have to move a directory now and then.

Comment: moving folders in the same file system is just shifting the folder entry; you don't actually move any data

Answer (score 0):

If your usernames change infrequently, the CPAN mindset might still have an advantage.  It's generally better to know for 90% of users where to drill down and find their content than to have to search N file structures looking for USERID.